# Reciting dikr while carrying janaza

Tags: practical-islam, quran-recitation

What is the Islamic rule regarding the recitation of dikr (praise) and Qur'anic verses loudly or softly while carrying Kansas?

Comment: I'd recommend to add some explanation: By Carrying janaza do you mean on the way to the cemetery and grave or while ditching the grave or while burying the dead? These are 3 different stages and in more or less all of them the body would be carried, and customs and more or less sahih hadith have different transmissions about what is preferably done at each one of them!

Answer (score 1):

**In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful**

According to your inquiry as you asked:

> What is the islamic rule regarding the recitation of dikr and quranic
>   verses loudly or softly?

Apparently the dhikr (ذکر) of **لا اله الا الله** (LaElaaha Elallah)  is considered as  the most common dikr for Jenazah (or during carrying...)

---

As a helpful related hadith, it is quoted that Imam Jafar-al-Sadiq (الامام جعفر الصادق) as the sixth Imam of Shia said:

> No Muslim says (recites) loudly لا اله الا الله  unless at once his
>   sins pour (fall) under his foots; as the leaves (leafs) of the trees
>   falls.

---

**Reference:**

- [ketaab.iec-md.org](http://ketaab.iec-md.org/paadaash_mojaazaat/paadaash_mojaazaat_sheikh-sadooq_01.html)